# VB2010 reading a text file into a datagridview but only certain fields/lines

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to read through a text file but then displaying ONLY certain fields back to my DataGridView, not the whole file. I set the delimiter as " + " and then want to show the file where the field starts with for example EQD.
My file looks something like this where each line is sepearted by a " ' ":

```
UNB+UNOA:1+++160804:0850+1+++++1'

UNH+402+BAPLIE:1:911:UN:SMDG15'

BGM++580691+9'

DTM+137:2016080408 50:301'

TDT+20+6217++++MACS:172:166'

LOC+5+NAWVB:139:6'

LOC+61+ZACPT:139:6'

DTM+178:1608020718:201'

DTM+133:1607030700:201'

DTM+132:160702:101'

LOC+147+0121282::5'

MEA+WT++KGM:4200'

LOC+6+PTLEI'

LOC+12+ZADUR'

RFF+BM:1'

****EQD+CN+CXRU1123659+45R1+++4'****

NAD+CA+MACS:172:20'

UNT+2339+402'

UNZ+1+1'
```

The code I currently have is:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System
Imports System.Collections

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim sourceFilename1 As String
        'Dim finalFile As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        'Dim origFileData() As String = File.ReadAllText(sourceFilename1).Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "").Split({"'"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "BAPLIE Files (*.*;*.*)|*.*;*.*"

        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
            sourceFilename1 = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        End If

        Dim TextFieldParser1 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(sourceFilename1)

        TextFieldParser1.Delimiters = New String() {"'"}
        TextFieldParser1.ReadLine.StartsWith("EQD+CN+")

        'If sourceFilename1.StartsWith("EQD+CN+") Then
        '    numberString = sourceFilename1.Substring(sourceFilename1.IndexOf("CN+"), 14)
        '    txtLastName.Text = numberString.Substring(3)
        'End If

        While Not TextFieldParser1.EndOfData
            Dim Row1 As String() = TextFieldParser1.ReadFields()
            If DataGridView1.Columns.Count = 0 AndAlso Row1.Count > 0 Then
                Dim i As Integer
                For i = 0 To Row1.Count - 1
                    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column" & i + 1, "Column" & i + 1)
                Next
            End If
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Row1)
        End While

    End Sub
End Class
```

I am not experienced at programming and doing this as a pet project.

Comment: I have updated my code and it seems to work now. Only problem is, it only shows ONE line/row in my datagridview, instead of the whole file's info????  here is my new code:

Comment: `TextFieldParser` uses only the `vbNewLine` character as line separator, so it will work if you replace all `'` in the file with new lines. Also, please delete your answer below if it does not answer your question, and update your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have re-written my code. I get my file to display the correct info on one line only, BUT now it only show ONE line in my datagrid if I run my program?

here is my new code:

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System
Imports System.Collections

Public Class Form1
    '------THIS IS GOOD 
    Private Sub btnRun_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRun.Click
        Dim sourceFilename2 As String = "*.edi | *.txt"

```
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
        sourceFilename2 = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If

    Dim strm As IO.Stream = IO.File.OpenRead(sourceFilename2)
    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(strm)
    Dim sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
    Dim line1 As String = ""
    Dim trimchars() As Char = {"+", "'"}

    grdMydata.Columns.Add("Column1", "POD") ' ------------------------- INDEX 0
    grdMydata.Columns.Add("Column2", "BAY") ' ------------------------- INDEX 1
    grdMydata.Columns.Add("Column3", "SLOT") ' ------------------------ INDEX 2
    grdMydata.Columns.Add("Column4", "VGM WEIGHT") ' ------------------ INDEX 3
    grdMydata.Columns.Add("Column5", "WT WEIGHT") ' ------------------- INDEX 4
    grdMydata.Columns.Add("Column6", "CONTAINER ID") ' ---------------- INDEX 5
    grdMydata.Columns.Add("Column7", "ISO CODE") ' -------------------- INDEX 6
    grdMydata.Columns.Add("Column8", "FULL/EMPTY") ' ------------------ INDEX 7
    grdMydata.Columns.Add("Column9", "CARRIER") ' --------------------- INDEX 8

    Do While sr.Peek() <> -1

        Dim Newline As String
        Newline = System.Environment.NewLine

        line1 = sr.ReadLine()

        '-----------------The file info in the text box
        'txtTopRows.Text = UNH+402+ & BAPLIE:1:911:UN:SMDG15' BAPLIE VERSION
        If line1.Contains("SMDG15") Then
            txtTopRows.Text = "BAPLIE ver 1.5  "
        End If
        If line1.Contains("SMDG20") Then
            txtTopRows.Text = "BAPLIE ver 2.0  "
        End If
        If line1.Contains("SMDG22") Then
            txtTopRows.Text = "BAPLIE ver 2.0  "
        End If
        'DTM+137:2016080408 50:301'
        If line1.Contains("DTM+137") Then
            txtTopRows.Text = txtTopRows.Text & Newline & "File Date : " & (line1.Substring(8, 10))
        End If
        'Port of load here
        If line1.Contains("LOC+5") Then
            txtTopRows.Text = txtTopRows.Text & Newline & "Port of Load : " & (line1.Substring(6, 5))
        End If
        'Port of Discharge here
        If line1.Contains("LOC+61") Then
            txtTopRows.Text = txtTopRows.Text & Newline & "Port of Disharge : " & (line1.Substring(7, 5))
        End If

        '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Dim row1 As Integer = Me.grdMydata.Rows.Add()
        'grdMydata.Rows.Clear()

        '''''Code to get all data on ONE row
        row1 = grdMydata.CurrentCell.RowIndex

        If line1.TrimStart(trimchars).StartsWith("LOC+147") Then
            grdMydata.Rows(row1).Cells(1).Value = (line1.Substring(8, 3))
            grdMydata.Rows(row1).Cells(2).Value = (line1.Substring(8, 7))
        End If

        If line1.TrimStart(trimchars).StartsWith("MEA+VGM") Then
            grdMydata.Rows(row1).Cells(3).Value = (line1.Substring(13, 5))
        End If
        If line1.TrimStart(trimchars).StartsWith("MEA+WT") Then
            grdMydata.Rows(row1).Cells(4).Value = (line1.Substring(12, 5))
        End If

        If line1.TrimStart(trimchars).StartsWith("EQD") Then
            grdMydata.Rows(row1).Cells(5).Value = (line1.Substring(7, 11))
            grdMydata.Rows(row1).Cells(6).Value = (line1.Substring(19, 4))

        End If
        If line1.TrimStart(trimchars).StartsWith("NAD+CA") Then
            grdMydata.Rows.Item(row1).Cells(8).Value = (line1.Substring(7, 3))
        End If

        Dim blank As Boolean = True
        For Each _row As DataGridViewRow In grdMydata.Rows
            blank = True
            For i As Integer = 0 To _row.Cells.Count - 1
                If _row.Cells(i).Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso _row.Cells(i).Value <> "" Then
                    blank = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If blank Then
                If Not _row.IsNewRow Then
                    grdMydata.Rows.Remove(_row)
                End If
            End If
        Next

    Loop
    sr.Close()
    sourceFilename2 = Nothing
    sw.Stop()

    txtDisplay1.Text = String.Format("File loaded in: {0} miliseconds" _
                                     & vbCrLf & "Number of Containers: {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, grdMydata.Rows.Count)

    'MsgBox ("Hai" & vbCrLf & "Welcome")
End Sub


Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Dim sourceFilename1 As String
    Dim sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
    sourceFilename1 = Nothing
    sw.Stop()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

If none of the values in the file contain `+` or `'`, then you can use the `Split` function:

```
Dim text = File.ReadAllText(sourceFilename1)
Dim lines = Split(text, "'")

For Each line in lines
    Dim values = Split(line, "+")
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(values)
Next
```